# Sources on covering tefilin shel yad

Tags: tefilin

I've read several things about covering the tefilin shel yad :

- covering it with the tallit while fixing it
- covering it with the tallit for the entire tefila
- covering it with the shirt sleeve for the entire tefila
- covering it with the jacket sleeve for the entire tefila

It seems that different sources are linked to kabbalah and the fact that it is not proper to pray with a bare arm or with a jacket sleeve hanging down

Do you have some details about those points ? Also I have noticed some rabbanim don't seem to pay attention to those things for example Rav Ovadia Yossef shlita.
Thanks.

Comment: Frank, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the excellent quesiton! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: possibly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8350/why-does-the-tefilin-shel-yad-have-a-protective-cover

Answer (score 5):

Since I see the Mishna Berura was already brought down, I will bring down the Kaf HaHaim, Orah Haim 27:56.

> ‫ ובשל יד אין להקפיד אם הם גלוים או מכוסים. והרב הלבוש כתב תש"י יהיו מכוסים בבגדו דכתיב לך לאות ולא לאחרים לאות.
>
> And, with the arm one, there's no need to be careful about it being either covered or uncovered. And Rav Levush wrote that Tefilin of the arm should be covered with his garment,  as it is written "... for you, as a sign ..." - but not for other as a sign.

(community translation)

He pretty much says to cover the Tefilin with the clothing (see Birke Yosef 27:5 and Kesher Gudal 3:12).

Comment: Perhaps you should quote the relevant parts here.

Comment: The asker mentioned several different ways to cover your shel yad. Which ones do your sources recommend? What's the lashon?

Comment: He says the Levush says to cover it. He himself writes "and the [Tefillin] of the hand, one does not have be particular if they are revealed or covered"

Comment: No, he is quoting the Lashon of the Rama (who quotes the Mordichi)- the rama says "Ubshel Yad En LeHakpid Im Hem Geluyim Or Mechusim." (see the Rama 27:11 Orah Haim).

Answer (score 4):

*Mishna B'rura* 27:47 says it's best to cover the *t'fila shel yad*. *Shaare T'shuva* there cites *kabala* as saying to cover it with the *talis* specifically, and points us to *Magen Avraham* 8:3, who also cites that from *kabala*, but then adds (if I'm reading him right) that one should not cover it *completely* with the *talis*.

As always, for practical *halacha*, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR).

Comment: Although the question was more from a _kabala_ perspective, my answer is more form a _halacha_ perspective: not what the OP was seeking, but more to my own taste. I do hope others can answer better the OP's actual question.

Answer (score 3):

The source in the Pesukim is Shemoth, 13:9.  וְהָיָה לְךָ לְאוֹת עַל-יָדְךָ (And it shall be a sign for you on your hand/arm).  The implication is that it should be something for you that others don't see.

I don't know the Torah SheBe'Al Peh source(s) that mention(s) these ideas.  They were told to me as a young teen literally Be'al Peh by my Rav.

Also, it is a Mitzvah that is not restricted to prayer, but which can, in theory, be fulfilled all day long. It is, I think, therefore, not the most impressive way to perform the Mitzvah if it looks like it's being done haphazardly with one shirtsleeve rolled up and one's jacket sleeve dangling down at the side. But that is just my opinion. It seems to me much more respectful if the shirt/jacket sleeve is worn over the Shel Yad, such that the entire arm is covered with the sleeve just as the other arm is covered, assuming that it fits, of course.

Comment: "assuming that it fits, of course" Every bar mitzvah kid complains that he can't get his shirt/jacket on over the tefillin. But I've never had an issue with either, though you need to do it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I heard in a shiur that covering the yad and not the rosh relates to the hidden nature of God (our usual experience in the world of action) vs His revealed nature (relating to כתר of the ספירות which is beyond our understanding). I came here looking for a written source for that. The zohar in ואתחנן does say that the rosh parallels the שמע and the yad parallels ברוך שם כבוד, which themselves represent these ideas.
You can see in בן איש חי וירא that there are conflicting kabbalistic traditions about whether to cover the head with the talis. I assume they are reflecting different images as opposed to an actual מחלוקת but not sure.

I hope this helps get us closer, and I hope someone can help me find more info about this too.