# Why does the Tefilin Shel Yad have a protective cover?

Tags: halacha, minhag, tefilin, protective-casing

When you purchase Tefilin, the Tefilin Shel Yad has a protective cover. Why? Is it Halachically necessary?

[image: Picture of tefillin and protective cover on the side. Cover is square to fit around the bayit, with a circular hole in the center.]

Comment: I lost a cover and need a replacement.  Is there a way I can determine the size so I can ask for a replacement?

Comment: @BruceJames: I think that would make a superb question!

Comment: @BruceJames, the downvote [there](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29266) was mine and was because the question was unclear. (I noted the inclarity in my comment there, and even gave you a little time to edit the question, before downvoting.) Now that I've edited the question to remove the inclarity, I've also removed my downvote. Note that inclarity is one of the reasons for downvoting: see the tooltip that appears when you put your mouse over the downvoting button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> (*D'varim* 6:8) וּקְשַׁרְתָּם לְאוֹת עַל יָדֶךָ

From this פסוק it is understood that the arm *t'filin* should serve "as a sign for you" in the sense of "exclusively for you", in which case they should not be exposed to the rest of the world while worn. The head box, on the other hand, is

> (*ibid.*) וְהָיוּ לְטֹטָפֹת בֵּין עֵינֶיךָ

which is understood to mean "to be seen", and therefore has no such need.

The *Ram"a* is not concerned about the specific requirement to cover them. Although he does hold of the need for exclusivity, he holds that it is achieved through placement on the arm, and nothing more (O.C. 23:11). Others hold, based on teaching of the *Ariza"l*, that mystical concerns overtake this lack of necessity anyway because the *t'filin* need to be worn modestly - even if noone else is around.

Comment: Ashkenazim specifically avoid allowing any kind of covering over the Shel Rosh, while most attempt to cover the Shel Yad in some fashion in addition to the (now generally hard plastic) cover that you get with it when you buy it. Many Sepharadim, on the other hand, do cover the Shel Rosh.

Comment: Based on the בן איש חי וירא it sounds like that פסוק is not the source for covering the של יד but more of a hint to it.

Answer (score 15):

I am a Sofer Stam and I can tell you that although there is an inyan in Kabbalah to cover the tefillin shel yad, that is not the reason for the plastic cover. It is to protect the corners of the bayit from getting worn down from years of rubbing against your clothing.

In places where there is Birchat Cohanim every day, some Cohanim put a similar cover on their shel rosh for Birchat Cohanim so the rubbing of the Tallit doesn't wear down the corners.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61312

Answer (score 12):

From my research, it seems [Jake](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8350/why-does-the-tefilin-shel-yad-have-a-protective-cover/8356#comment-10635) is correct.

I looked into this inyin a couple years ago when helping write a Bar Mitzvah pshetl on the subject of the Shel Yad being covered and the Shel Rosh being uncovered.

At the time I heard from both my Rov as well as from a Sofer (who is also a Talmud Chochom) that the requirement to cover the Shel Yad (as [WAF correctly mentioned and sourced, herein](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8350/why-does-the-tefilin-shel-yad-have-a-protective-cover/8354#8354)) should be met by using one's shirt, jacket or Tallis and that the purpose of the small, black Shel Yad cover that comes with the Tefilin is simply to protect the Shel Yad and to prevent its squareness from being compromised precisely due to it otherwise rubbing against one's shirt/jacket/Tallis.

It seems that this is apparent from the fact that often (if not always) the small, black Shel Yad cover that comes with the Tefilin has a hole in it and so does not completely/properly cover the Tefilin box as is required.  On this last note, I was told that purpose of the hole is so one can easily access/touch the actual Bayis of the Shel Yad (not just its cover) as required at various points during davening (e.g., when saying the words "ukshartem l'os al yadecha" in Shema) without having to remove the protective cover.

Comment: C.K., welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for sharing the benefit of your investigation! Please consider registering your account, to help the site keep track of your contributions no matter where you log in from.

Comment: "as required": more like "as is customary"

Comment: Interesting and informative note about the hole!

Answer (score 6):

A simple answer would be to protect the corners of the Tefillin, so that they don't accidentally get knocked into something and possibly disqualified, since the Tefillin must be as square as possible (See [here](http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/mb/18mb.htm) and [here](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/bar-mitzvah/05.htm#t22)).

However, this doesn't answer why we don't have a protective covering for the Shel Rosh as well, since it too must be square.

This is probably since the Shel Rosh should be seen, as the Gemara ([Megilla 16B](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1444&size=1)) says (English from [here](http://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Megilah.pdf) page 64):

> And all the peoples of the earth shall see that the name of the Lord is called upon thee, and they shall be afraid of thee" (Devarim 28:10) and it has been taught: R. Eleazar the Great says that this refers to the phylactery of the head.

The [Beis Yosef says](http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/mb/18mb.htm) that the Shin on the Tefillin Shel Rosh represents G-d's Name, which is referenced in the Passuk.

Many do cover the Tefillin Shel Yad, by contrast, based on the sources found [here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/eng/?id=3185). It is possible that the protective cover is considered enough of a covering by some people. From what I've seen however, most people who are careful to cover it, do so with their shirt (even if they have a protective cover for their Shel Yad).

Comment: I think the reason for the protective covering on the shel yad is precisely because people cover it with their shirts and it rubs against the corners of the tefillin, possibly compromising their squareness.

Comment: As others said the plastic covers don't accomplish covering so it can't be seen

Answer (score 1):

The general explanation [given by @WAF](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8354/759) is correct, but from what I have heard, the Pasuk from which it is learned that specifically the Tefillin Shel Yad are "exclusively for you" is a *different* one, namely *Exodus 13:9* :

> וְהָיָה **לְךָ** לְאוֹת עַל יָדְךָ וּלְזִכָּרוֹן בֵּין עֵינֶיךָ לְמַעַן תִּהְיֶה תּוֹרַת ה' בְּפִיךָ כִּי בְּיָד חֲזָקָה הוֹצִאֲךָ ה' מִמִּצְרָיִם

Sorry, but I do not have the source for this right now.

Comment: I believe you are correct. This was the Pasuk my rabbi referenced when I was a young man in one of my first few times putting on Tefillin.