# Replacing a lost cover for a tefillin shel yad

Tags: tefilin, size, protective-casing

[My tefillin shel yad had a cover that could slip on and off](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8350/why-does-the-tefilin-shel-yad-have-a-protective-cover) but the cover is lost and needs replacement. Is there a way I can determine the size so I can ask for a replacement?  Are there standard sizes?

Comment: Why not a ruler?

Comment: How about a [vernier caliper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caliper#Vernier_caliper)?

Comment: ... another approach - are you fundamentally asking if there are standard tefillin sizes (like an American Size 9 sneaker)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there are standard sizes, though obviously there are usually going to slight variations in fit for every pair of handmade tefilin. The sizes seem to be measured by <strike>cm<sup>2</sup></strike> millimeters. Based on my experience they tend to err towards a looser fit; I usually adjust this by adding a sticker or a piece of paper on the inside.

This piece is sometimes called a "yadlich," and a quick Google brings me to http://keterjudaica.com/Yadlich-Tefillin-Holder.html

(There's [another page](http://www.worldofjudaica.com/judaica/tefillin#f_item_type=1001&price=1-804&RPP=30&total_results=null&sort=popularityDESC&group=) that uses the same size values but claim them to measure "cm.")