# Tefillah shel rosh cover

Tags: product-recommendation, tefilin, how-to, birchas-kohanim

B'ezrat Hashem I plan on going to Israel next month, however, this presents a small problem. As a Kohen, I will be duchaning every day, while wearing my tefillin. Due to the placement of the tefillah shel rosh, this presents a minor problem, inasmuch as the rubbing of the tallit over the ketzitza (box of the tefillin bayit) will invariably cause my tefillin to lose their ribuah (squareness). As a result, most Jews wear a cover over the tefillah shel yad, however, I have not seen such a thing for a shel rosh.

Does anyone know where to get/how to make a cover for the tefillah shel rosh?

Comment: I doubt that it will lose its squareness to pasul it

Comment: @sam, we may however apply the old adage, "better safe than sorry"

Comment: What do other kohanim in Israel do?

Comment: @DanF, if you look in the Siddur Ish Matzliach, it shows how a Sephardi man is supposed to wear tallit and tefillin. It says that one should cover the sh"r על דעת האר”י. Thus it is presumably mutar, although it is customary to leave it uncovered and it is certainly customary to not remove the tefillin during duchaning in Israel.

Comment: Does it mean to cover it completely or to make a gaag (roof) over the teffilim

Comment: @sam, the illustration shows the tefilla shel rosh completely covered, IIRC.

Comment: @ Noach @Daniel I have never seen anyone, not even a kohein, cover their *tfillin shel rosh*. And i am not a kohein, but how much can the tallit rub against the tfillin while duchening? It's what, 2 minutes?

Comment: @Scimonster, in my experience (only on Y"T) the tallit can move around quite a bit.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I located this - http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9861/5275. It seems this answerer knows something about this! You may want to "ping" him.