# What is the purpose of the plastic casing on the shel yad?

Tags: tefilin, protective-casing

On every pair of tefilin, as far as I know, there's a plastic casing that sits on shel yad, even as it is worn.

[image: .]

What is the purpose of it?

Comment: I bet Moshe Rabbeinu's didn't have a plastic case :)

Comment: Dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8350/759

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6462/759

Comment: Yes, dupe, but mine has a picture. Move the picture and close?

Comment: I can't 'merge' a picture, but you can always [suggest an] edit [to] the other post to improve it an clarify what it is talking about. Such an edit would be beneficial IMO.

Comment: Certainly not every pair, as @DoubleAA said. But an interesting question nontheless. I believe it's for protection. Going to the other question now to see if I was right!

Comment: Ohh, I was so close. I postulate that it is purely for protective purposes, Mah SheEin Kein with the Shel Rosh, as that is supposed to be visible. The fact that it generally has a hole in the top might indicate that it is _not_ meant to be a full covering. But I could be wrong.