# Shirts that accommodate the shel yad

Tags: clothing, tefilin

All of the button down shirts that I own cannot be rolled up past the elbow. To put on tefillin I need to roll the sleeve all the way to the shoulder. What do you look for in a shirt to determine that its sleeves will accommodate rolling so high?

Comment: I try and make sure the sleeves aren't too tight, but i wear tshirts, not button downs.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6462/5

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't roll them up. The [Mishnah Berurah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6465/5) and the [Levush](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11763/5) both write that, based on the [language of the Pasuk](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6463/5), it is best to keep the Shel Yad covered.

Most button-down shirts have sleeves that can be unbuttoned at the wrist, raised past the bicep, and then brought back down over the Shel-Yad for re-buttoning at the wrist.

Comment: "don't roll them up": you have to roll them up when putting the _shel yad_ on, no? And that's what the question says: "To **put on** tefillin I need to roll the sleeve all the way to the shoulder" (emphasis supplied).

Comment: @msh210, based on the statement, "All of the button down shirts that I own cannot be rolled up past the elbow," I understood "roll" to mean actually roll, not just pull. When you roll your sleeves up, they tend to be tight around the arm. When you pull them up without rolling, assuming the wrist of the sleeve is unbuttoned, it tends to be looser fitting.

Comment: @msh210, see: http://www.kosherimage.com/images/sweater01.jpg

Comment: @msh210, my assumption is that he is rolling the sleeve up so that it actually stays up and doesn't flop back down and cover the Tefillin. I'm recommending that he abandon that attempt in favor of the opinion that the sleeve should cover the Shel Yad, which would help solve his problem (and may even make his problem moot).

Comment: Don't know about your shirts, but all of mine have a _second_  button at the bottom of the slit at the end (which is about six inches down starting at the wrist). If you open that second button there is generally no problem rolling the sleeve up near the shoulder. After you put the tefillah on, you can put the sleeve back over it or your jacket on top.

Comment: I think "rolling" is the part that is confusing people.  If you actually roll the sleeve, as one might do if one were warm and wanted to bare his arms and not have the sleeve flop back down, it holds in place and is difficult to pull back over the Tefillah.  If instead of *rolling* it, you just raise it up close to the shoulder, there is usually, with most shirts, enough loose material to then lower the sleeve back down over the Tefillah after the Tefillah is in place.